# Convert date from dd-mm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to convert given date into the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Given date:

```
DECLARE @Date1 VARCHAR(50) = '30-01-2015'
```

Now I want to convert it into the `2015-01-30`.

## My try:

Try1:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'30-01-2015',126)
```

Try2:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'30-01-2015',120)
```

For both try the result remain same that is `30-01-2015`.

Comment: Because this is string not a `date`.

Comment: @Igor, Oh! Got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Date1 VARCHAR(50) = '30-01-2015'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, @Date1, 105), 23)
```

Comment: How to convert '31-12-99' to '9999-12-31' i.e. YYYY-MM-DD in SQL server

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, @Date1, 5), 23)

Comment: @Giorgi-Nakeuri Do we have equivalent function in MySql?

Answer (score 5):

Try this way

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,'30-01-2015',103)
```

Comment: One note on this. This is not formatting. It is just casting to date type.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, Exactly! And because of that reason I'm going to accept your answer.

Comment: How to convert '31-12-99' to '9999-12-31' i.e. YYYY-MM-DD in SQL server

Answer (score 1):

**Convert date from dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in SQL Server**

```
convert(datetime,'18-11-2019 00:00:00',105)   // will return 2019-11-18 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), CONVERT(datetime, my_date, 3), 120),10)
```

if you want to remove the time.  Also

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(datetime, my_date, 3), 120)
```